# Waffle: How to move issue to "in-progress" stage?

Tags: git, github, waffle

We are planning to use waffle for project tracking. We want to move the issue to "in-progress" automatically when work start. As per the recommendation [here](https://github.com/waffleio/waffle.io/wiki/FAQs#branch-moving)

> We move an issue into "In Progress" if you put the issue number at the
>   beginning of the branch name with a '-' or '_' behind it or anywhere
>   else in the branch name with a '#' in front of it.
>
> Here are some example branch names:
>
> 123-fix-bug
>
> bug-fix#123

In our case, We have published only master, staging & dev branches to remote repository. We create local branch for each issue or user story we work. These local branches are not published to remote.
In-fact once the work is done in local branch we merge the local branch to dev and publish the dev branch; and then delete the local branch. We don't want to publish every local branch to remote repository.

So having said that, how does naming the local branch certain way will help waffle to move issue to different state? because local branch is just on my machine.

I must be missing something here.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: no never got any valid answer..we started using JIRA